# after assign one object values to other variable. its change my old object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't understand why my data show wrong response anyone please help me this. I'm assign object to other variable named "`forlogging`" but i want my old object `response` same as i'm getting. but after assign value to other variable `forlogging` my old `response` automatically same as new one anyone help me this check below code

I want my personal text in `personalInfo`. but after assign `response` values in forlogging variable getting response variable also ********* stars why ??? and how to solve this

```
   var forlogging = {}
        forlogging = response;
        forlogging.succ = "00"
        forlogging.personalInfo = "**************"
       
        this.logger.info({ finalresponseClient : forlogging }, 'Final response ClientService') // fine data log
        return response   // response = personalInfo = "**************"
```

[image: check image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to make a copy of the object rather than passing the reference

Using spread operator

```
forlogging = { ...response }
```

Using Object assign

```
forlogging = Object.assign({}, response);
```